# Traverse neo4j: Result is filtered

Tags: neo4j

In a retailer reporting perspective you want to report how an article has performed and how many you have on stock. (very simplified).

Given the (sub)structure:

```
(Product)-[HasStock]->(Stock)
(Product)-[InSale]->(Sale)
```

Imagine we have 2 products:

```
P1 = {Id= 1, Color=Black, Size=L}
P2 = {Id= 2 ,Color=Black, Size=M}
```

Each has a stock entry in (Stock) of {Quantity = 2} (aka. 4 units are on stock)
In Sale we have:

```
S1 = {Id= 1, Product= 1, Quantity=1}
```

If I query the data for 
`P.Product,P.Color,P.Size,Sum(Stock.Quantity) as stockcount, Sum(Sale.Quantity) as sold` 
I always only get one result back with the P1 product and a stockcount of 2 (instead of 2 objects, with a sum(stock) = 4)....What I need is the "outer join" mechanism from Relational dbms....
How do I accomplish that?

(reworking the relations would be ok, but a product is not in a sale every day, so adding extra nodes to sales with empty relation would not be an option). (working on 100 millions of nodes).

Likewise I don't want to do a Cartesian product, since it will blow up the performance :(

Comment: Can you share you cypher query. ?

Comment: The query is like: `match(p:Product)--(stock:Stock) with sum(stock.Quantity) as stockcount, p as p match(p)--(sale:Sale) return p.Color,p.Size,stockcount` The Schema is like this:   `CREATE (:Product {Id: 1, Color: "Black", Size: "L"}),(:Product {Id: 2, Color: "Black", Size: "S"});
CREATE (:Stock {Id: 1, Product: 1, Quantity: 2}),(:Stock {Id: 2, Product: 2, Quantity: 2});
CREATE (:Sale {Id: 1, Product: 1, Quantity: 1});

MATCH (p:Product),(s:Stock)
where p.Id = s.Product
CREATE (p)-[:onStock]->(s);

MATCH (p:Product),(s:Sale)
where p.Id = s.Product
CREATE (p)-[:inSale]->(s);
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm sorry, but the query you've posted in the comments is very likely not your complete query. You don't return anything from the sale in it (and in your question you do).
2. Your problem is that you don't get results for the products that don't have sales. The match does not work and thus no results ... You can solve that with an optional match.

So that would be :

```
OPTIONAL MATCH(p)--(sale:Sale)
```

Any fields you then return from sale when there are no sales will have a null value.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom